# Микросервисная архитектура Java

Tags: java, микросервисы

Посредством чего или с помощью чего взаимодействует один микросервис с другим?

Comment: Посредством любых средств передачи информации. Упоминание о  RESTful для этого встречается чаще всего. Но можно использовать любые другие протоколы.

Comment: @Sergey получается суть микросервисной архитектуре - это создание множества rest-сервисов, каждый из которых выполняет только одну конкретную задачу?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Стоит добавить, что поскольку каждый каноничный микросервис -- это отдельный процесс, то теоретически для взаимодействия сервисов может использоваться что угодно из списка вариантов межпроцессорного взаимодействия. И хотя большинство способов взаимодействия сводятся к HTTP и очереди сообщений, сервисы могут "взаимодействовать" хоть через файловую систему. Например, может существовать сервис, который мониторит таблицу БД и выполняет определенную задачу с новыми/обновленными записями.

---

> получается суть микросервисной архитектуре - это создание множества
>   rest-сервисов, каждый из которых выполняет только одну конкретную
>   задачу?

Во-первых, просто сервисов. REST -- это уже деталь имплементации. К тому же, у сервиса вообще может не быть никакого API.
Во-вторых, создание множества сервисов -- это, конечно же, способ достижения цели. А суть микросервисной архитектуры заключается в следовании принципу единой обязанности. И уже отсюда вытекает все остальное: способы реализации, плюсы и минусы.

Answer (score 12):

Существует множество различных технологий взаимодействия одного микросервиса с другим. Сервисы могут использовать синхронные механизмы связи на основе запроса/ответа, такие как ***REST*** или ***Thrift*** на основе *HTTP*. В качестве альтернативы они могут использовать асинхронные коммуникационные механизмы на основе сообщений, такие как ***AMQP*** или ***STOMP***. Существуют также различные форматы сообщений. Сервисы могут использовать удобочитаемые текстовые форматы, такие как *JSON* или *XML*. Кроме того, они могут использовать двоичный формат (который более эффективен), такой как ***Avro*** или ***Protocol Buffers***.